# Why doesn't Entity Framework give an error when trying to insert a unique seeded column?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am following the Entity Framework guide on:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/data/jj200620

At the part where I need to add a Blog, I do the following:

```
var blog = new Blog { Name = "TEST123",
BlogId=3 }; 
db.Blogs.Add(blog); 
db.SaveChanges();
```

This will work without giving me any errors but the BlogId will be auto generated as it should because the table has the column as a unique seeded value.

Why isn't this giving me any error when I run the code? It's just inserting "TEST123" in the column for Name and auto generating the ids? I thought it should give me errors to warn me that the inserted value would not have a BlogId of 3?

Update: It doesn't give any errors but it does insert "TEST123" into the Blog database but with a BlogID that is not 3 and is set by the SQL Server.

Comment: I dont know which database you are using, but normally auto generated values can be overwritten if you set them explicitly

Comment: Because there is a property set to true in the property of the entity. I don't remember the name exactly but something like  StoreGeneratedPattern. It just ignores the values you provide. Change it and you will get an error.

Comment: If you don't want it to be auto-generated, you can use the attribute `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` applied on the `BlogId` property.

Comment: If you have an exception, please post the full error message and stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for the Entity Framework team, but I can think of three reasons:

1. Entity Framework has your data model, so it knows `BlogId` is auto generated, and thus will not include that column in the `INSERT` SQL command it sends to the database server;
2. Programmers would almost never want to set `BlogId` when they add a `Blog`, so therer is no point for Entity Framework to waste time in checking whether you've set `BlogId` to a value or not;
3. `BlogId` will be assigned a default value (i.e. zero) when you do `new Blog { ... }` without explicitly giving `BlogId` a value, so Entity Framework can not be sure whether you've set `BlogId` to a value or not, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

EntityFramework ignores the values for auto-generated columns like IDs. If you think of the situation when you make a new `Blog` object without specifying the `Id` property C# will assign it a `0` value because that is the default value for numeric types. So every time you want to insert something in the DB with EF you'll have an object with some value for ID and it should be a problem. That's why EF ignores the value of the ID properties of your DB models.